# Make a NG-Options value select in same function as populating list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-options

I am having some difficulties with selecting a value from an array in the same function that I populate the select using ng-options.  I am trying to dynamically load a select list full of options and at the same time there is a default value from the last time the user chose something that I want to already be selected. when console.logging I can see that this works and is added to machineProfile.input but the select does not reflect what the ng-model has as a current value. I did confirm that they are both the same. I have some code below.

```
 $scope.getMachineProfile = function(object) {

    var count = 0;
    var keepGoing = true;

    $scope.machineProfile.machineName = object.Name;

    $scope.machineInputs = object.Hardware;
    /*angular.forEach(object.Hardware, function(inputs, key) {

      console.log($scope.machineInputs);
    });*/

    //var foundMachine = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.machineProfiles, function(machine, key) {
      if (keepGoing) {
        if (machine.remoteAddr === object.Address) {
          keepGoing = false;


          /*$timeout(function(){

          }, 500);*/
          /*console.log($scope.machineProfiles[count].input);
          console.log($scope.machineProfile.input);*/
          $scope.machineProfile.input = $scope.machineProfiles[count].input;
          $scope.machineProfile.workType = $scope.machineProfiles[count].workType;
          $scope.machineProfile.workPeriod = $scope.machineProfiles[count].workPeriod;
          $scope.machineProfile.counterRate = $scope.machineProfiles[count].counterRate;
          $scope.machineProfile.timerRate = $scope.machineProfiles[count].timerRate;
          console.log($scope.machineProfile);
          //console.log('Awesome select: ' + count);
          //console.log($scope.machineProfiles[count].input);
        }
        ++count;
      }
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav sidebar-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="machine in machineObj" class="">
            <a ng-click="getMachineProfile(machine)">
                <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span>
                <span class="sidebar-title">{{machine.Name}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Below is once a item is selected from the code above:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="chooseInput" class="control-label">Choose Input</label>
            <!-- <select name="chooseInput" class="form-control"  ng-model="machineProfile.input">
                <option ng-selected="machine.input === machineProfile.input" ng-repeat="machine in machineInputs" value="machine.input">
                    {{machine.input === machineProfile.input}}
                </option>
            </select> -->
            <select name="chooseInput" class="form-control" ng-model="input" ng-change="awesome(machineProfile.input)" ng-options="machine.input for machine in machineInputs track by machine.input"></select>
            <!-- <input disabled="true" name="machineName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Machine Name"> -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated as this is driving me nuts. The $scope object machineProfile.input is updated but nothing appears on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `ng-model` is not correct. Try this.

```
<select name="chooseInput" class="form-control" ng-model="machineProfile.input" ng-change="awesome(machineProfile.input)" ng-options="machine.input for machine in machineInputs track by machine.input"></select>
```